# Compilar en Visual Studio Code mediante accesos directos de teclado

Tags: c, vscode, compilar

No se si es posible hacer lo que quiero, pero como veo que Visual Studio Code es muy personalizable..

Resulta que tengo un proyecto de un video juego realizado en **C** con el framework *jo-engine*. Dicho framework **para compilar, dispone de un fichero .bat** que personalizas y ejecutas en la consola generando unos ficheros compilados.

Trabajar en vscode me es muy cómodo la verdad, pero **cada vez que quiero compilar, abro el terminal en vscode y en la ruta donde está mi directorio de desarrollo ejecuto el fichero "compiler.bat"**

Me gustaría saber si es posible y a través de que herramientas, hace que a través de unas **teclas de acceso directo** tipo ctrl+shift+f7 en vscode **se ejecutara directamente lo que hago en el terminal** sin tener que estar siempre yendo a la consola y volviendo a ejecutar la línea anterior una y otra vez, *simplemente por ir un poco más rápido*, tipo el compilar con F5 de Visual Studio.

Gracias!

Comment: No tengo ni idea de lo que preguntas.. pero sabes que la consola es una ventana dentro de vscode que esta siempre abierta no?

Comment: ¿ Es posible ? Si. ¿ A través de que herramientas ? Pues como todo en VSCODE, con sus archivos de configuración. En concreto, [`tasks.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) (Menú `Terminal / Configurar tareas ...`).

Comment: @Trauma pues esta va orientada un poco a lo que quiero hacer pero tengo que acceder a través de menú. Voy a ver si puedo asociar el Run Task a una combinación de teclas y creo que con eso estaría todo listo. 

gbianchi si eso lo sé. Muchas gracias a los dos por vuestro tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que deberás hacer es crear un archivo tasks.json en tu proyecto (dentro de la carpeta .vscode).
En este archivo creas una tarea:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [

    {
      "label": "Build",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "compiler.bat",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "dedicated",
        "group": "compiler",
        "clear": true
      },
    },
}
```

Una vez generada la tarea, abres los métodos abreviados del teclado (Ctrl + K Ctrl + S) y añades algo como lo siguiente:

```
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+r",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "Build"
  },
]
```

A partir de este momento, cuando pulses Ctrl + r se lanzará la tarea.

Comment: Muy útil, gracias!

Comment: Si te ha resultado útil, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada XD